# Проверка на наличие товара

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Такая ситуация, есть на сайте несколько разных товаров, например, яблоки, груши и мандарины. Как мне при помощи php и mysqli узнать, куплены ли они?
Если более конкретней, то после покупки товара, информация о том, что товар куплен, должен заноситься в таблицу. Но проблема в том, что мне кажется, что бред делать 3 колонки: apples, pears и mandarins. А если у меня товаров больше? Есть какая-нибудь альтернатива? Есть способ, которым можно сделать это проще?

Comment: В чем проблема-то? у вас есть таблица где столбцы - это свойства товара, а строки - сам товар, вот одно из свойств - сколько осталось(это как пример). если 0 значит товара нет.

Comment: Нет, видимо не совсем конкретно задал вопрос. Есть таблица с пользователями, в ней должно быть указано, купил ли пользователь товар или нет. Он может купить все товары, но как это должно выглядеть? Если у меня на сайте 10 товаров, то должно быть 10 столбцов в таблице для пользователей?

Comment: ну не, можно наподобии логов сделать: у каждого товара есть уникальный номер, например id1,id2,id3.. Каждый пользователь например u1,u2,u3, Количество товара c1,c2,c3,c4. Вам нужна табличка состоящая из трех столбцов: `Кто`, `Что` и `Сколько`. ну и строки там будут типа `u1, id2, c4`, `u2, id2, c1`. И если вам нужно узнать кто сколько купил, то вы пишете запрос, мол покажи мне все записи где столбец `Кто` равен `u1`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую данную тему.